# How to center divs inside another div with position:absolute?

Tags: css

```css
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    text-align: center;
}
#logo-img img {
    float:left;
    height: 4.3vw;
}
#logo-text {
    float:left;
    font-size:2vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
    <div id="logo-img">
        <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="logo-text">Lorem Ispum Dolores</div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding `left:50%;right:50%` but it doesn't align it horizontally right in the middle. What is the right way to horizontally align divs in my situation?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8s0q9cyq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `text-align: center`?

```css
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#logo-img,
#logo-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#logo-img img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4.3vw;
}
#logo-text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <div id="logo-img">
    <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" />
  </div>
  <div id="logo-text">Lorem Ispum Dolores</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to upvote once you got rid of those unneeded floating elements :)

Comment: Didn't know that ```display: inline-block``` is a must attribute in my situation, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tachi I added some extra code too to make it align with the image. Have a look at it!

Comment: And hence the upvote ;P. @Tachi: It's not a 'must', but gets rid of `float`: which, IMHO, brings a lot more complications further down the line

Answer (score 4):

I improved Praveen's answer: https://jsfiddle.net/9mpgdqzf/

Dont use a div with an ID only to give style to an IMG. The Img can have the ID and and inherit all the attributes directly into it and your HTML becomes cleaner and lighter ;)

```
<div id="logo">
    <img id="logo-img" src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" />
    <div id="logo-text">Lorem Ispum Dolores</div>
</div>

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  text-align: center;
}

#logo-img, #logo-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#logo-img {
  height: 4.3vw;
}
#logo-text {
  font-size:2vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    text-align: center;
}
#logo-img {
    display:inline-block;
}
#logo-img img {
    height: 4.3vw;
}
#logo-text {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:2vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
    <div id="logo-img">
        <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" />
    </div>
       <div id="logo-text">Lorem Ispum Dolores</div>
</div>
```